# Why does numpy say this matrix is singular *sometimes*?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Part of my code inverts a matrix (really an ndarray) using numpy.linalg.inv. However, this frequently errors out as follows:

```
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

That would be fine if the matrix was actually singular. But that doesn't seem to be the case.

For example, I'm printing the matrix before trying to invert it. So right before the error it prints this:

```
[[ 0.76400334  0.22660491]
[ 0.22660491  0.06721147]]
```

... and then returns the above singularity error when it tries to invert that matrix. But from what I can tell this matrix *is* invertible. Numpy even seems to agree when asked later.

```
>>> numpy.linalg.inv([[0.76400334, 0.22660491], [0.22660491,    0.06721147]])
array([[  2.88436275e+07,  -9.72469076e+07],
   [ -9.72469076e+07,   3.27870046e+08]])
```

Here's the exact code snippet:

```
print np.dot(np.transpose(X), X)
print np.linalg.inv(np.dot(np.transpose(X),X))
```

The first line prints the matrix above; the second line fails.

So what distinguishes the two actions above? Why does the stand-alone code work even though it errors out in my script?

EDIT: Per Colonel Beauvel's request, if I do

```
try:
    print np.dot(np.transpose(X), X)
    z = np.linalg.inv(np.dot(np.transpose(X), X))
except:
    z = "whoops"
print z
```

it outputs

```
[[ 0.01328185  0.1092696 ]
[ 0.1092696   0.89895982]]
whoops
```

but trying this on its own I get

```
>>> numpy.linalg.inv([[0.01328185, 0.1092696], [0.1092696, 0.89895982]])
array([[  2.24677775e+08,  -2.73098420e+07],
   [ -2.73098420e+07,   3.31954382e+06]])
```

Comment: are you sure it's this input creating this issue? can you use a try catch in your code (for example if you use a loop) to know exactly when it occurs? What is X furthermore?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel: I'm pretty sure it's this input, because print np.dot(np.transpose(X), X) returns the matrix I wrote above, and then the next line produces the error.

Comment: there is no reason it fails so ... can you be sure with a try catch and put a pdb.set_trace() in case of fail so that you can investigate the code ?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel: see edits above

Comment: Do you need numpy to do an inverse on a 2x2? The question is valid as to why it's failing, but there's a simple formula for this if you want to roll your own with more precision. Probably a one-liner with numpy :)

Comment: Also, the example you added does not raise an exception for me - what precision is that matrix?

Comment: @en_Knight: I'm just doing 2x2 by for now, but I plan to invert larger matrices later. Not sure if this is what you mean, but the numbers just 'float's. Perhaps they should be 64bit or something?

Comment: @lamb_da_calculus fair enoguh. The numerical instability problems with matrix inversion aren't going to get any better with bigger matrices :)

Comment: I am no expert in numpy, but could it be that it doesn't work because it isn't a native array? In the example where it works, you give it a native list, in the other one it doesn't. Seems to be a problem inside numpy. Try to convert it to a native list, and use it than. (Although I know that this isn't a particular beautiful solution.)

Comment: @CodingLambdas: I guessed something like this too, but using z = np.linalg.inv(np.dot(np.transpose(X[j]),X[j]).tolist()) in the try block above leads to the same error.

Comment: Sorry, then I can't help, except if... Sry, but I have to ask: Are you sure you are using the same versions of python in the script and in the shell? Try to include `print numpy.linalg.inv([[0.01328185, 0.1092696], [0.1092696, 0.89895982]])` in your script. I want to know if that works...

Comment: @CodingLambdas: That's a good suggestion, but that snippet does work correctly in the script, so I don't think it's a version mismatch issue.

Comment: This is just crazy. There are two options: Your system is kind of weird or your python installation is kind of weird. Or a third one: Numpy is kind of weird. I don't know...

Answer (score 4):

It's a matter of printing precision. The IEEE 754 doubles, that you're most likely using, have about 16 decimal digits of precision and you need to write out 17 [to preserve the binary value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Character_representation).

Here's a small example. First create a singlular matrix:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.random.seed(0)

In [3]: a, b, c = np.random.rand(3)

In [4]: d = b*c / a

In [5]: X = np.array([[a, b],[c, d]])
```

Print and try to invert it:

```
In [6]: X
Out[6]: 
array([[ 0.5488135 ,  0.71518937],
       [ 0.60276338,  0.78549444]])

In [7]: np.linalg.inv(X)
LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

Try to invert the printed matrix:

```
In [8]: Y = np.array([[ 0.5488135 ,  0.71518937],
   ...:               [ 0.60276338,  0.78549444]])

In [9]: np.linalg.inv(Y)
Out[9]: 
array([[-85805775.2940297 ,  78125795.99532071],
       [ 65844615.19517545, -59951242.76033063]])
```

Succes!

Increase printing precision and try again:

```
In [10]: np.set_printoptions(precision=17)

In [11]: X
Out[11]: 
array([[ 0.54881350392732475,  0.71518936637241948],
       [ 0.60276337607164387,  0.78549444195576024]])

In [12]: Z = np.array([[ 0.54881350392732475,  0.71518936637241948],
    ...:               [ 0.60276337607164387,  0.78549444195576024]])

In [13]: np.linalg.inv(Z)
LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

Answer (score 1):

I just compute the determinant:

```
In [130]: m = np.array([[ 0.76400334, 0.22660491],[ 0.22660491,0.06721147]])

In [131]: np.linalg.det(m)
Out[131]: 2.3302017068132921e-09

# which is in fact for a 2D matrix 0.76400334*0.06721147 - 0.22660491*0.22660491
```

Which is already quit close to `0`.

If a matrix `m` can be inverted, mathematically you can compute the adjoint and divide by the determinant to get the inverted matrix.
Numerically if the determinant is too small, this can entail the kind of error you have ...

Comment: The determinant is indeed small, but this doesn't seem to explain why numpy can do the inversion when I ask it later.